# Why does CBP put the date stamp over the visa?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, passport-stamps

Why does the US Customs & Border Protection officer sometimes stamp the date over the non-immigrant visa? Is it an error or does it means something else?

Comment: stamp date means the entry/exit stamp?

Answer (score 1):

It just means that the visa has been used at least once.  See also

- [My US visa has been stamped over by the immigration officer. Would this cause any issues?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/100707/1940)
- [Unusual placing of a second impression of a USA visa immigration stamp. Does it mean anything?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/87339/19400)